# How i can display a image

Tags: ios

How can I display a image automatically 5 seconds after I open a page and this move ?

i have this piece of code, the image is display automatically 5 seconds after I open a page but its not move why.

```
class yourViewController: UIViewController{

 @IBOutlet weak var moveobj: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad(){
     super.viewDidLoad()
     moveobj.hidden = true
     moveobj.alpha = 0
     NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: #selector(UIViewController.showMyBtn), userInfo: nil, repeats: false) 
   }

  func showMyBtn(){
         UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {

        self.moveobj.hidden = false
        self.moveobj.alpha = 1
        })

     }

}
  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {


        super.viewDidAppear(animated)


        let orbit = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        var affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0)
        affineTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(affineTransform, CGFloat(M_PI))
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 198 - (100/2),y: 135 - (100/2)), radius:  CGFloat(155), startAngle: CGFloat(255), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)


        orbit.path = circlePath.CGPath
        orbit.duration = 3
        orbit.additive = true
        orbit.repeatCount = 0.2
        orbit.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced


        moveobj.layer .addAnimation(orbit, forKey: "orbit")
```

Comment: Instead of posting code that does work, post the code that you are having trouble with. And explain what "doesn't work" means. In what way, specifically, doesn't the code work?

Comment: @rmaddy i have edited  the question